# Give auto-suggest for drop-down on my DynamoDB hash key

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, autosuggest

My use-case is that I want to be able to provide the user an auto-suggest feature in drop-down box where user starts typing first few characters and he should be shown suggestions.

The problem is that the field I want the suggestions on is also the hash key for my DynamoDB table. And queries on hash key have to specify the full value of hash key and not with prefix.

Can anyone suggest a good DynamoDB pattern for this use-case?

Comment: How many rows are in that table? Could you pre-load them into memory, or supply a complete list and do the filtering in the app rather than the database?

Comment: for now, there are 1000 rows and it can be possible.
But, I am keeping versioning support as well (with version as sort key). And, so it may grow maybe 10X in say a month or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10,000 entries with, say, 20 characters = 200K. This is totally feasible to keep in memory and would be *very* fast to access.

Compare this with performing a database query every time the user types a character in the drop-down box and you'll be making maybe 10 database calls as they type. Then, multiply by the number of concurrent users and you could conceivably be hitting **hundreds of database accesses per second**. The DynamoDB table would need to be provisioned with a high Read Capacity to support this.

It would be much more sensible to keep it in memory, or use [Amazon DynamoDB Accelerator (DAX) – Fully managed in-memory cache for DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/dax/) or [Amazon ElastiCache](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticache/) table.

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice solution that solves my problem